# Angular4 on change select box returns wrong value

Tags: angular

I want to do something in change event, but change event is returning a value with colon prefix. How to get correct value without prefix and colon?

**education.component.html**

```
<select class="form-control custom-select" name="course_id" id="course_id" formControlName="course_id" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let course of course_list" [ngValue]="course.id">{{ course.name }}({{course.id}})</option>
</select>
```

**education.component.ts**

```
onChange(value) : void {
   console.log('Course Value',value)
}
```

**For Example:** I'm getting the value **2:8**. Expected value is **8**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just use `[ngValue]` when you want to bind *objects*.

So, as `value.id` is a *primitive* value, use `[value]` instead of `[ngValue]`:

```
<option *ngFor="let course of course_list" [value]="course.id">{{ course.name }}({{course.id}})</option>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Tq

Comment: Can you check it as answer? :)

Comment: sure! @developer033